# Can't install sample dataset on Kibana - Forbidden Error

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, kibana

Installed Kibana and Elasticsearch on my macOS Catalina via Brew (not sudo), but I'm not able to install the sample data sets. Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this Forbidden error and how to resolve? The error message is on the bottom right of the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to the conf of elasticsearch uncomment and fill the path.logs line with the right path

Answer (score 1):

**Check if you have enough(>90%) disk space available**

A good way to look for reason of any error is **logs** if available :) 
I was trying to load Sample Data (eCommerce orders, flight , web logs) in to my kibana. I was getting some error. Logs shown below
**elasticsearch.log**
`[o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [/Users/xyz/Installs/ElasticSearch/elasticsearch-7.9.3/data/nodes/0] free: 15.1gb[6.4%], shards will be relocated away from this node; currently relocating away shards totalling [0] bytes; the node is expected to continue to exceed the high disk watermark when these relocations are complete`

My MAC has total 250 GB space, I freed up extra 20 GB, then it worked. Please check if you have enough memory (more than 90% should be available)

Answer (score 0):

go to management -> index pattern -> create index pattern.

Comment: it just gets stuck with spinning / loading circle and doesn't create the index pattern

Comment: check into elasticsearch logs, you might get hint whats happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for some reason I hit the threshold where the indexes are locked because of no more disk space and so I had to unlock the indexes manually 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-create-index-pattern-from-kibana/167184